# Creating a security application for Windows

Tags: .net, windows, security

First, let me state that I'm an intermediate .NET developer, so going low-level is out of the question.

Essentially I just want to write a program that will monitor the system for changes and log/report those changes. It doesn't need to block any changes and I don't believe I would be able to even if I wanted to considering the language it's being written in. I'm just not sure what all I would need to check.

These ideas come to mind:

- Check and store the MD5 sum of system files and everything linked to
  startup in the registry, and if they don't match a trusted MD5 then
  scan with VirusTotal or a similar service
- Check running processes for trusted MD5 sum, upload unknown to
  VirusTotal
- Monitor services
- Monitor listening ports

Of course detecting anything outside of ring3 is out of the question.

Any other ideas of things to check? Is this feasible or should I just stick with the popular anti-malware software?

**Edit:** Another idea that comes to mind is checking running processes for their path and reporting an out-of-place executable. Maybe regex scan for random file names as well. Also possibly validating the executable header of running processes, and reporting invalid header information as I've heard that binding a file will make part of the header (PE?) invalid. Validating the certificate of the file too, although I've seen malware with a faked cert that passed UAC before.

Time for more research, thanks everyone!

Comment: Are you trying to create your own anti-malware system? If it's for learning purposes, fair enough, but if it's for actual usage, I'd recommend using standard ones that are already available. `MalwareBytes` is pretty good. Main advantage of popular ones, besides implementation, is the fact that their signatures are regularly updated.

Comment: hmm md5?  I guess you aren't really into security otherwise you would know better.

Comment: @Rook has md5 been broken badly enough that you'd be able to generate a collision for arbitrary files? One thing is a SSL certificate, executable binaries are larger. Not trying to defend use of MD5, I'm just curious :)

Comment: @snemarch yes 100%.  An attacker can create a md5 collision for an arbitrary file using nothing more than a modern desktop machine using the md5 prefixing attack.   Defeating a trip wire is exactly the kind of attack that a hash collision is useful for.  If you don't understand that then you have absolutely no business creating such a security system.

Comment: @Rook thanks - hadn't followed MD5 attacks since I moved to SHA-256, scary that md5 is utterly broken.

Comment: @snemarch Wow,  I can think of no bigger cryptographic mistake than knowingly using a broken primitive to enforce a security policy.  Any cryptographer worth his salt should cringe at reading your statement.

Comment: @snemarch also good read: http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/

Comment: This is only for learning purposes and wouldn't be used by anyone but me. I'm doing this to learn more about security and programming. Thank you for the information about MD5, I'll use SHA-256 instead as suggested by snemarch.

Answer (score 2):

> Any other ideas of things to check? Is this feasible or should I just
>   stick with the popular anti-malware software?

Unless you are doing this for learning purposes, probably. For learning purposes, not a bad exercise at all. In other words, I wouldn't try to single-handedly compete with existing products, nor would I safeguard my own machine solely with homegrown code; even if it was well-tested, you have to keep up on the latest issues and exploits.

I spent some time doing due diligence on a product like this for a startup company. They achieved something similar to what you are seeking, but performance was severely degraded. Even for mainstream products, performance can be a problem.

Comment: Completely for learning purposes, I know that I can't create anything close to anything on the market, which is why I'm here asking how I should go about it :). I use Comodo with Defense+ in paranoid mode and MSE, I only want to learn more about security and programming. That being said, do you have anymore input? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Windows machine, I think it would be better to use a malware scanning tool. Unless you will use the Microsoft Antivirus API, I think you can easily run into file locking problems.

But if you want to monitor services and listening ports, it can be made by using built in framework classes.

Comment: Didn't know about Microsoft Antivirus API, thanks for that! I'll look into the different classes involved in network, service, driver, file, etc monitoring. Really I was mostly looking for input as to whether the steps I listed are even useful, and to get suggestions on other things that I might monitor. Cheers